# How do I aggregate promises generated from async functions within a Node.js stream callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, typescript, promise

I have a Node.js Typescript program in which I'm trying to parse large CSV files line by line and do something with those lines asynchronously. More specifically, I need a function that will:

1. Open a CSV file.
2. Parse the next line to an object.
3. (Ideally) Collect a set number of objects for batch processing.
4. Pass the object(s) to an async function for processing (returns a promise).
5. Collect the promises from the processing function.

Some requirements and considerations:

- I need to poll any of these promises for progress.
- Assume these CSV files are large; streaming line by line is necessary.
- I shouldn't block the application while these processing operations are running.
- Returning an array of promises may not be the right approach, especially if I'm trying to read a file with a million lines.
- I need a hook of sorts to cancel or retry a failed operation.

Here's some test code I've gotten working. `ObjectStream` is a custom Node.js Transform that converts CSV lines to objects.

```
function parseFileAsync(filePath: string): Promise<any> {
    var doParseFileAsync = (filePath: string) => {
        var streamDeferred = q.defer<Promise<any>[]>();
        var promises: Promise<any>[] = [];
        var propertyNames: string[] = [];

        var stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: "utf8" })
            .pipe(new LineStream({ objectMode: true }))
            .pipe(new ObjectStream({ objectMode: true }));

        stream.on("readable", () => {
            var obj: Object;
            while ((obj = stream.read()) !== null) {
                console.log(`\nRead an object...`);

                var operationDeferred = q.defer<any>();
                operationDeferred.resolve(doSomethingAsync(obj));
                promises.push(operationDeferred.promise);
            }
        });
        stream.on("end", () => {
            streamDeferred.resolve(promises);
        });

        return streamDeferred.promise;
    }

    return doParseFileAsync(filePath)
        .then((result: Promise<any>[]) => {
            return q.all(result);
        });
}
parseFileAsync(filePath)
    .done((result: any[]) => {
        console.log(`\nFinished reading and processing the file:\n\t${result.toString()}`);
    });
```

The final `done` call is executed before the stream even starts running, because `parseFileAsync` immediately fulfills with an empty array; the stream hasn't had a chance to push any promises yet.

After days of searching, I'm still not sure what the correct way to do this is. Node/JavaScript experts: help?

## Update

The code has been updated, and my promises are now playing nicely. However, I need a way to hook into the stream and cancel the process if desired. I also need a way to retry any operations that failed.

Comment: My initial thought (without reading too much into this) is that you should choose one paradigm or another. This seems best handled by something like [`map stream`](https://github.com/dominictarr/map-stream) in the stream paradigm. If you _must_ use promises (perhaps a consumer expects a promise) just return a promise and resolve it whenever your streams have all exited.

Comment: Make a new promise P that is done when stream is done adding it's promises to a list. Return P and have it resolve the list of promises. Wait for P, then wait for all P's results.

Comment: @nick Sticking with streams isn't possible. The application I'm working on uses promises. I'm only now introducing a feature that requires file reading.

Comment: Gotcha. I think you can still use the approach in the latter half of my comment. E.g. just wrap the streamy behavior in a single promise.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; they worked perfectly! I've made some updates to my original question; I need a hook for cancel and retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into some limitations in the program's architecture that wouldn't allow me to pass promises around as freely as I wanted. So instead, rather than kicking off a bunch of promises, I decided to wait until the previous batch finishes before starting on a new one. Here's the approach I took:

1. Separate the stream stuff into its own function that accepts continuation tokens. The return value will contain the data read as well as a continuation token if there's more data to be read:

   ```js
   function readFile(filepath: string, lines: number, start: any): Promise<any> {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Define a function that will run the retry-able operation. Within the body of this function, retrieve and process a chunk of data from the file. If the result has a continuation token, "recursively" call the operation function again:

   ```js
   function processFile(filepath: string, next: any): Promise<any> {
       var chunkSize = 1;
       return readLines(filepath, chunkSize, next)
           .then((result) => {
               // Do something with `result.lines`
               ...
               if (result.next) {
                   return parseFile(filepath, result.next);
               }
           });
   }
   ```

And voila! A long-running operation that operates on chunks and is easy to report progress on.